# How to control the attributes of dots only in a layer_boxplots?

Tags: r, ggvis

I have a ggvis boxplot and I am trying to map some values to the dots (for example different `size`). How could I do it? So far I have something like this, but none of the two layers is properly aligned to the categories on the x-axis:

```
  mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~factor(cyl), y= ~disp) %>% 
  layer_boxplots(size:=0 ) %>% 
  layer_points(size := 10)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have just noticed that the alignment issues with the boxplot are there even if I just plot `layer_boxplots`

```
mtcars %>% mutate(cyl=as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~cyl, y= ~disp) %>% 
  layer_boxplots()
```

but can't figure out why ggvis does that

Comment: Related to https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/366 ?

Comment: @lukeA Thanks, I found my answer here https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/242 for aligning the two layers, but still can't align the grid

Answer (score 0):

To get the boxplot centers lined up on a factor axis, you can use the `padding` argument in `scale_nominal`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
    ggvis(x = ~cyl, y= ~disp) %>% 
    layer_boxplots(size:=0) %>% 
    scale_nominal("x", name = "xcenter", padding = .9)
```

As you saw in the [linked github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/242), use `prop` with `scale = "xcenter"` to get the points lined up.

```
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
    ggvis(x = ~cyl, y= ~disp) %>% 
    layer_boxplots(size:=0) %>% 
    layer_points(size := 10, prop("x", ~cyl, scale = "xcenter")) %>%
    scale_nominal("x", name = "xcenter", padding = .9)
```

[image]